# How to handle two types of json responses?

Tags: json, laravel

The response of a request is different depending on how many cotas my client has.

Let's see some code:

```
//Validar Cliente
        $clienteSiaconSOAP = new \SoapClient('http://xxxxxx/Services.asmx?WSDL');
        $paramClienteSiacon = array(
            'iDDD' => 0,
            'iNumeroTelefone' => 0,
            'iCPF_CNPJ' => $request->nroCpfCnpj,
        );
        $responseClienteSiacon = $clienteSiaconSOAP->ROS_ValidarCliente($paramClienteSiacon);
        foreach ($responseClienteSiacon as $clienteSiacon) {
            $cSiacon = json_decode(json_encode($clienteSiacon), true);
        }

        return $cSiacon['Cliente'];
        die();
```

If the client does have one cota, the response is:

```
{"CODIGO-TIPO-PESSOA":"F","CPF-CNPJ":"*******","CODIGO-GRUPO":"04921","NUMERO-SEQUENCIA":0,"NUMERO-COTA":47,"NOME-CLIENTE":"SILVA SOUZA","NUMERO-CONTRATO":*****,"DESCRICAO-BEM":"Pacote de Servi\u00e7os 102","VALOR-BEM":11565,"NUMERO-TELEFONE":"034 888888888","DATA-PROXIMA-REUNIAO":"20150511","SITUACAO-COBRANCA":"Q","DESCRICAO-SITUACAO-COBRANCA":"Quita\u00e7\u00e3o","FASE-SITUACAO-COBRANCA":"Q000","CODIGO-PLANO-COTA":36,"DATA-ENTREGA":"20130624","DATA-CONTEMPLACAO":"20130613","PERC-TOTAL-PAGO":100,"PERC-TOTAL-PENDENTE":0,"PERC-QUITACAO":0,"CODIGO-FORMA-PAGAMENTO":1,"DATA-NASCIMENTO":"19661027","DATA-CANCELAMENTO":"","CADASTRO-ATUALIZADO":"S","SEGMENTO-CADOC":6,"CEP":38406392}
```

And if a client has more than one cota, the response is:

```
[
{
"CODIGO-TIPO-PESSOA": "J",
"CPF-CNPJ": "00635344000177",
"CODIGO-GRUPO": "07384",
"NUMERO-SEQUENCIA": 0,
"NUMERO-COTA": 853,
"NOME-CLIENTE": "AUTO ESCOLA GUILHERMITTI E L LTDA",
"NUMERO-CONTRATO": 859866,
"DESCRICAO-BEM": "HONDA NXR 160 BROS",
"VALOR-BEM": 12975,
"NUMERO-TELEFONE": "017 32581859",
"DATA-PROXIMA-REUNIAO": "20190322",
"SITUACAO-COBRANCA": "N",
"DESCRICAO-SITUACAO-COBRANCA": "Normal",
"FASE-SITUACAO-COBRANCA": "N000",
"CODIGO-PLANO-COTA": 31,
"DATA-ENTREGA": "20180507",
"DATA-CONTEMPLACAO": "20170622",
"PERC-TOTAL-PAGO": 87.7196,
"PERC-TOTAL-PENDENTE": 3.1401,
"PERC-QUITACAO": 12.2804,
"CODIGO-FORMA-PAGAMENTO": 1,
"DATA-NASCIMENTO": "",
"DATA-CANCELAMENTO": "",
"CADASTRO-ATUALIZADO": "N",
"SEGMENTO-CADOC": 4,
"CEP": 15115000
},
{... and 3 more ... ]
```

I am without ideas on how to deal with it. I have tried count(), sizeof() but the result on the first case is like 26 and at the second, 4 which makes more sense in this case, cause there are 4 cotas at the second scenario.

It is needed 'cause if the client has more than one cota, must show a list of it.

Any ideas, please?

Comment: why you  json_encode and json_decode your response? you know what that means or no?

Comment: I've tried response()->json($var), but the results were inconclusive as it is now... don't think it the problem but agree: response()->json is much cleaner, right?

Answer (score 0):

As my old brother always says, "Code less, Produce more".
I used the strlen() to get the size of the response and it works like a breeze!

```
 if (strlen($cSiacon) > 916) {
            return 'É multi cota';
        } else {
            return 'É mono conta';
        }
        die();
```

As the minimum size is always 916, it is done!